# Zend gData check if folder exist (Google Docs)

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-docs, gdata

I have this code to create a folder,
Before creating it i would like to check if this folder doesn't already exists!

```
$service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getHttpClient($_SESSION['cal_token']);
$docs = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);
$docs->createFolder('My Folder');
```

I would like something like

```
if($docs->isFolder('My Folder')) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: i've got the impression that nobody knows how Gdata works on Stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A folder in Google Docs is identified by a category with scheme `http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind` and term `http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#folder`:

```
<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
          term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#folder"/>
```

You can check whether an entry is a folder by calling `getCategory()` to list all of its categories and looking for a category like the one above.